# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore]

Tags: flutter

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore]
 D:\doctor_chat\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16

Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Im getting above error in my code. how to solve this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your app Navigate to `android/app/build.gradle` and change minsdk from 16 to 21

[image: Here is an image]

Hope it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 3):

go in your project to `android/app/build.gradle` file and edit the `minSdkVersion` to:

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Update minSdkVersion 16 to 19 in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    minSdkVersion 16 // change it to 19 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the following changes in "build.gradle" file under "yourapp/android/app/"

```
minSdkVersion: 19
targetSdkversion: 28
```

It should work as usual now

Answer (score 0):

File Location :- ....\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy

Change this line
"static int minSdkVersion = 16" To " static int minSdkVersion = 21"

Answer (score -1):

Starting from flutter 2.8 you should change `minSdkVersion` from `android/local.properties`

Comment: I am using flutter 3.10.6 (latest), but there is not any any key `flutter.minSdkVersion` in `local.properties`